# traverse a tree having more than two children from top to bottom to get values in java and then traverse bottom up to again adjust values

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, tree-traversal

I have a tree which can have more than two children so it is not a binary tree. In fact it can have n no. of children and it can have n-levels as well.

If I start from the root(has an id) then, the children have the root's id as parent id and the children have their own id as well. Similarly if I go to the next level children the upper level nodes id will serve as parent id for this level.
How do I need to traverse?
Starting from root node, on basis of root node id I will find the children(have root node id as parent id) then I need to retrieve some data from these children and do some calculation. Moving to next level which I will find when I will pass these children ids and then again do some calculation. The process continues until I don't find any records on basis of Ids.
Further I also need to traverse in reverse direction to do some deductions.

I am working with spring boot and mongodb. Using spring data mongodb.

Entity structure
-id
-parent id
- type 
- amount
- vendor id.

I need a solution to traverse this sort of tree and retrieve the data. 
This is also a performance critical task.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would add `children` field to the `structure`
So traversing down the tree will be just [Depth-fisrt search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Recursive implementation would be:

```
private static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
public int findItem(someCondition) {
  if (check(someCondition)) { 
    return id;
  }
  for(Structure child:current.getChildes()) {
    int childResult = child.findItem(someCondition);
    if (childResult != NOT_FOUND) {
      return childResult;
    }
  }
  // this node and its childes are not comply with someCondition
  return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

Depth-fisrt search could be written in iterative way.

This method will finish in O(N) and visits each node **only once**. If you can't change the structure then you have to visit each node at each level and spend O(N*n) time.

If you want to search faster than O(N) you need for some sorting like [K-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). In cost of adding in O(log N) time you get searching in O(log N) time.

Building path is more simple:

```
Structure current = this;
while (current.getParent() != null) { 
  current = current.getParent();
  path.add(current.id); 
}
```